# django 1.10 csrf_token not creating hidden input field

Tags: django, csrf

I have a form, but Django is not creating a hidden input like -

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="80NGejzAPl2aCbEEuyLqIT3ppMTJLilY">
```

If trying send a form I have 403 mistake, CSRF token missing or incorrect.

This is my code:

html

```
<form class="get-info" action="{% url 'callback:send_callback' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %} ... </form>
```

middleware

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import BadHeaderError, send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, request
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib import messages

def callback(request):
    phone = request.POST.get('phone', None)
    lastpath = request.POST.get('lastpath', None)
    if validatePhone(phone):
        if sendMail(phone):
            messages.success(request, 'Мы скоро перезвоним Вам')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(lastpath)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка в отправке запроса. Попробуйте позже.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(lastpath)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Неверный формат номера телефона. Телефон нужно вводить в формате +99999999999")
        args = {}
        zzz = lastpath.render(RequestContext(request, args))
        return HttpResponse(zzz)
```

Callback url -

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^callback/', views.callback, name='send_callback'),
]
```

Form rendering on the main page:

```
<form class="get-info" action="/callback/callback/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="karpaty-perezvonite-mne">
    <input id="callback" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control"    placeholder="+ 380 ___-__-__">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="lastpath" value="/" style="display: none">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying submit form to the main page - "/" and now have such mistake

```
UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  
This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your middleware setting should only contain `CsrfViewMiddleware` (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware)). The `CsrfResponseMiddleware ` was [removed in Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-4) and `django.template.context_processors.csrf` is a template context processor which Django uses automatically when you use `render`. You don't need the `args.update(csrf(request))` line if you use `render`. Is the form submitted from the `callback` view? Please add the url patterns.

Comment: Which URL is the form submitted from? How is the form with the CSRF token rendered in the template (click "view source" in your browser).

Comment: It's difficult to read code in the comments - please [edit] your original question. You still haven't said which URL you submit the form from. You are trying lots of things like `csrf(request)` and `RequestContext` which you simply do not need in modern Django. If you use `render` in the view that displays the form, then the CSRF token should work without problems.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: I can see the form is being submitted *to* `/callback/callback/`. You still haven't said which URL the form is being submitted from. The first version of your question used `return render(...)` which is correct. The new version with `lastpath.render()` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have found the problem - it was "render" of the main page where form was situated. Thank's to all.